# how can I use uwsgi web.py to run background function?

Tags: python, multithreading, web.py, uwsgi

Say I need to send an email to myself when there is new comment.
and I don't want to block web.py presenting HTML to browser.
and Threading seems don't work here.

```
class comment:
    def POST(self):
       ...
       sender = Thread(target=_sendmail,args=('New Comment',msg))
       sender.start()
       referer = web.ctx.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'http://www.domain.com')
       raise web.SeeOther(referer)
```

the problem when using threading is that once POST function is finished.. the sender within it would be freezed..usually sender didn't finish its job.
And I certainly don't want to use sender.join() to wait for sender to end.

I think uwsgi don't have anything to do with this..
but I saw a explanation suggested that uwsgi suspended the web.py app.when there's no request.or request is done.
web.py provide an approach called @background.. http://webpy.org/cookbook/background
But it's seems have certain problems.it doesn't clean up threaddb dictionary.
and it would add an argument to the url like http://domain.com:8080/?_t=3080772748   which is ugly.
Is there an better solution? **sending an email while serve url request as usual.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no problem in using threads in uWSGI, but remember to enable them with --enable-threads otherwise the GIL (for performance reasons) it is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks! There it is!. It never occurred to me that it was uWSGI would freezing threads without --enable-threads..