# CGI python script enable background thread

Tags: python, multithreading, cgi

I am trying to run a method in a background thread in python,

below is my following code :

```
process_thread = threading.Thread(target=process_data,args=[params,data])
process_thread.start()
```

the issue here is, by the time the process_data function is compeletely executed the response is returned to the client and the connection is closed.

In the process_data function i am setting database values, but since the connection is closed the database values are not being set.

I dont want to use thread.join() to wait for the process_data to finish its execution, as the data will be very large and there will be connection timeout.

Is there any other solution, where i can execute this method in a thread and set the values.

i am using CGI and python 2.6.6

i tried "thread.daemon = True" but it didnt help, i have also checked the post here "[how can I use uwsgi web.py to run background function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308718/how-can-i-use-uwsgi-web-py-to-run-background-function)" but here he is using uwsgi which may not be of much help to me as i am using CGI.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you should be using `wsgi` instead if you have a problem of not having longlived processes.

Comment: Maybe starting a new *process* instead of a thread will work for you. IMHO it is a better choice for what you seem to be trying to do.